# How do you create a custom command in a plugin in CakePHP 4?

Tags: cakephp

I am building a Command in a plugin, but having difficulty reconciling the [plugin example](https://book.cakephp.org/4/en/plugins.html#commands) in the book with [the Command one](https://book.cakephp.org/4/en/console-commands/commands.html). I get this:

```
Exception: Cannot use 'MyNamespace\MyCommand' for command 'my_namespace my'. It is not a subclass of Cake\Console\Shell or Cake\Command\CommandInterface.
In [/path/to/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Console/CommandCollection.php, line 68]
```

In looking closer at CommandCollection::add() I see

```php
    /**
     * Add a command to the collection
     *
     * @param string $name The name of the command you want to map.
     * @param string|\Cake\Console\Shell|\Cake\Console\CommandInterface $command The command to map.
     *   Can be a FQCN, Shell instance or CommandInterface instance.
     * @return $this
     * @throws \InvalidArgumentException
     */
    public function add(string $name, $command)
    {
        if (!is_subclass_of($command, Shell::class) && !is_subclass_of($command, CommandInterface::class)) {
            $class = is_string($command) ? $command : get_class($command);
            throw new InvalidArgumentException(sprintf(
                "Cannot use '%s' for command '%s'. " .
                "It is not a subclass of Cake\Console\Shell or Cake\Command\CommandInterface.",
                $class,
                $name
            ));
        }
...
```

Two things jump out:

1. Why is it checking for `$command` to be a subclass of an interface?  Shouldn't it be iterating over `class_implements()` instead to check?
2. The exception message looks like it has a typo: shouldn't it reference `Cake\Console\CommandInterface` instead?

If there's a more complete example of creating a custom plugin with a Command, I'd appreciate a pointer to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `\Cake\Console\Shell` doesn't implement an interface, so `class_implements()` wouldn't work. `\Cake\Console\Command` (respectively the new `\Cake\Command\Command`) does implement an interface, so `class_implements()` would work, but so does `is_subclass_of()`, it checks for interfaces too, so it doesn't really make a difference.
2. Yes, it should. This might have been changed accidentally when commands have been moved into the `Command` namespace (`\Cake\Command\Command` was previously `\Cake\Console\Command`).

The error message suggests that your custom command class neither extends `\Cake\Command\Command` (or `\Cake\Console\BaseCommand`), nor implements `\Cake\Console\CommandInterface`, or that the value passed to `CommandCollection::add()` points to a wrong/non-existent class.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation - #2 is now fixed in CakePHP - https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/pull/15972